# Android MediaPlayer: File Access in Android Q and above

Tags: java, android, android-external-storage

I'm writing a mediaplayer app which I want to migrate to Android Q.
I use MediaStore to query the audio files and store artist, album, path, etc. in my SQLight database.
If I want to play an audio file, I fetch the path from the database (SQL query) and set it as mediaplayer.setDatasource(path). Trying that, I get an open failed: EACCES (Permission denied) error message.

The user can select the directory where the audio files are stored using a filechooser.

```
 Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE);
 intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_DEFAULT);
 intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION |  Intent.FLAG_GRANT_PERSISTABLE_URI_PERMISSION);
 startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Choose directory"), PICK_AUDIO_REQUEST);
```

In `onActivityResult` I set the permissions on the selected directory like

```
     Uri uri = data.getData();
     int takeFlags = data.getFlags();
     takeFlags &= (Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION |
     Intent.FLAG_GRANT_WRITE_URI_PERMISSION |Intent.FLAG_GRANT_PERSISTABLE_URI_PERMISSION);
```

When I try to use the path in mediaplayer `mMediaPlayer.setDataSource(path);`

I got the following error:

```
 open failed: EACCES (Permission denied)
```

Using `android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true"` isn't a solution that I want to have implemented.

In **manifest.xml** I set the permissions:

```
   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

Please help.

Thanks, GGK

Comment: "When I try to use the path" -- there is no path, because this is not a file. The tree could be on cloud storage, for all you know. Use [the `setDataSource()` that takes a `Uri`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer#setDataSource(android.content.Context,%20android.net.Uri)) "I set the permissions on the selected directory like" -- that `takeFlags` code is not useful. Call `takePersistableUriPermission()` on a `ContentResolver` to get long-term access rights to the chosen tree.

Comment: Doing that, I got an error like `No persistable permission grants found for UID 10144 and Uri content://media/external/audio/media` although I have set the permission in fileChooser...use `getContentResolver().takePersistableUriPermission(uri,Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);` on the uri returned from the fileChooser

Comment: `content://media/external/audio/media` is not the `Uri` that you got back from `ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE`. Call `takePersistableUriPermission()` on a `ContentResolver`, passing in the `Uri` that you got from `ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE`.

Comment: You are right, I had a mistake in my code...now I got the contentUri from `ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE` ...Now I got `UnsupportedOperationException: Unsupported Uri content://com.android.providers.downloads.documents/tree/downloads`...is there a uri conversion necessary?

Comment: OK, let me try again. You are calling `startActivityForResult()` with an `Intent` containing `ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE`. You are getting a `Uri` back in `onActivityResult()`, representing the tree the user chose. You want long-term access to that tree. Hence, in `onActivityResult()`, call `takePersistableUriPermission()` on a `ContentResolver`, passing in the `Uri` delivered to you in `onActivityResult()`.

Comment: Yes, So I do. I fetch the uri from `ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE` (`uri = data.getData()`), then set the `getContentResolver().takePersistableUriPermission(uri, Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION
                    | Intent.FLAG_GRANT_WRITE_URI_PERMISSION);` Then I take this `uri` to set the contentResolver like `Cursor cur = getContentResolver().query(uri, projection, selection, selectionArgs, sortOder);` So I get the `UnsupportedOperationException: Unsupported Uri content://com.android.externalstorage.documents/tree/3339-6133%3AStorage%20Card%2FAudioFiles`

Comment: I do not know what the `query()` is for. You do not show that in your question, and I did not call for it in a comment. To work with a document `Uri` such as the one you got from `ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE`, you can use `DocumentFile`. See [this](https://commonsware.com/blog/2019/11/02/scoped-storage-stories-documentfile.html) and [this](https://commonsware.com/blog/2019/11/09/scoped-storage-stories-trees.html).

Comment: I want to give the user the possibility to configure a specific audio directory, so I want to query this directory using a `ContentProvider`to get Albumname, Artist, Albumart etc....from all files in this specific directory. Playing a mediafile (e.g. mediaplayer) will probably work using `DocumentFile` (but I didn't already try it.

Comment: "to get Albumname, Artist, Albumart" -- none of that data exists. "I want to give the user the possibility to configure a specific audio directory" -- so long as that is a subdirectory of a traditional audio location (e.g., `Music/`), you can use `RELATIVE_PATH` to store things in custom locations (see [this](https://commonsware.com/blog/2019/12/21/scoped-storage-stories-storing-mediastore.html)).

Comment: "use RELATIVE_PATH - thanks, I will try this, but it meens a lot copy traffic when some users have many audiofiles on the device and memory requirements  will also increase.  In Android < Q I can fetch audiofiles from every directory the user sets in the SettingActivity, with Android >= Q I can't do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved by using

```
childrenUri = DocumentsContract.buildChildDocumentsUriUsingTree(mUri,
            DocumentsContract.getTreeDocumentId(mUri));
cur = getContentResolver().query(childrenUri, null, null, null, null);
```

Thanks @CommonsWare for supporting me

Answer (score 0):

you need to add

**android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true"**

in androidManifest file which help in access file from Q.

Comment: This is not  a solution I would like to have because next releases will not support this manifest entry